# Blazor InputSelect options are appearing below the dropdown list not in it

Tags: blazor

I am using Blazor InputSelect for the first time and whatever I have tried so far the options appear below the control not in it. It is not related to INT ID not being available in Blazor as in the actual code it is a string.

```
                   <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <InputSelect id="rep" @bind-Value="debtormasterfile.s_rep" class="form-control"/>
                    @for (int i = 0; i <= listreps.Count() - 1; i++)
                    {
                        <option value="@i>@listreps[i]</option>
                    }
                   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not rendering your options inside the `<InputSelect>` element. Try changing your code to this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <InputSelect id="rep" @bind-Value="debtormasterfile.s_rep" class="form-control">
        @for (int i = 0; i <= listreps.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i>@listreps[i]</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>
</div>
```